# how to get the value 'variation_id' in this array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array in wp/woocommerce:

```
Array ( [0] => Array(    [variation_id] => 18919    [variation_is_visible] => 1    [is_purchasable] => 1    [attributes] => Array(   [attribute_seleccionar-opcion] => precio-nino) [image_src] => [image_link] => [image_title] => [image_alt] => [price_html] => $380,00    [availability_html] => [sku] => [weight] =>  kg    [dimensions] => [min_qty] => 1    [max_qty] => [backorders_allowed] => [is_in_stock] => 1    [is_downloadable] => [is_virtual] => 1    [is_sold_individually] => no)  [1] => Array(    [variation_id] => 18921    [variation_is_visible] => 1    [is_purchasable] => 1    [attributes] => Array(   [attribute_seleccionar-opcion] => precio-adulto) [image_src] => [image_link] => [image_title] => [image_alt] => [price_html] => $399,00    [availability_html] => [sku] => precio adulto    [weight] => 200 kg    [dimensions] => 1 x 2 x 3 cm    [min_qty] => 1    [max_qty] => [backorders_allowed] => [is_in_stock] => 1    [is_downloadable] => [is_virtual] => 1    [is_sold_individually] => no)  )
```

I need make a foreach me back this value 'variation_id' and show this( get_post_meta many as ' variation_id ' has the array ):

```
echo get_post_meta(18919, 'precio_normal_euro', true ); echo get_post_meta(18921, 'precio_normal_euro', true );
```

thank´s u"

Comment: `echo $myArray[0]['variation_id'];`

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

I think that should help.

```
$key = 'variation_id';
foreach ($myArray as $arr) {
  if (isset($arr[$key])) {
    echo get_post_meta($arr[$key], 'precio_normal_euro', true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

good ideas, thanks... I have solved this way:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($available_variations); ++$i) {
$value_ = $available_variations[$i]['variation_id'];
echo 'precio normal €:'.get_post_meta($value_, 'precio_normal_euro', true );
echo 'precio rebajado €:'.get_post_meta($value_, 'precio_rebajado_euro', true );
```

}

Show this: `precio normal €:5precio rebajado €:55precio normal €:100precio rebajado €:120`